# Filter collection issue

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have a `ComboBox` with a collection of custom objects bound to it:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CreatedMacros}" Width="150" Height="25"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"                                
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMacro}"/>
```

In some other place I have an `ItemsControl` with a View bound to it:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="stackMacros" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewMacros}">
```

Where the view is defined this way:

```
    private ICollectionView _viewMacros;
    public ICollectionView ViewMacros
    {
        get
        {
            return _viewMacros;
        }
        set
        {
            _viewMacros = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ViewMacros");
        }
    }
```

And intialized and filtered like this:

```
         ViewMacros = CreatedMacros as ICollectionView;
         ViewMacros = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CreatedMacros);

         ViewMacros.Filter = delegate(object o)
         {
             if (((Macro)o).PrivateMacro== false)
             {
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
         };
```

The issue is that at both places I get the filtered results. My aim is to edit some macros in the editor, and display them as buttons in other place. But only non-private macros should be there, that's why I'm using the filter, distinguishing with the `PrivateMacro` property.

How could I display in the `ComboBox` the whole collection and in the `ItemsControl` only the filtered results?

Comment: looks like your approach is OK (with the use of `ICollectionView.Filter`), so what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting `defaultView` over source collection, create new `CollectionViewSource` and assign its view to `ViewMacros` if you don't want the sorting and filtering in original source collection -

```
ViewMacros = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = CreatedMacros }.View;
```

**UPDATE**

When you bind to any collection say `ObservableCollection`, WPF binding engine internally creates a View on top of your collection and bind to that. It can be `ListCollectionView` or other dervied versions of `ICollectionView`.

> Remember that we never bind directly to the collection; there is
>   always a view on top of that collection that we bind to. If you are not providing any view, default view is created behind the scenes.

So, when you ask for `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()`, it will return the view which it has created internally over that collection. Hence any filtering and sorting will be applied on same collection sine both are referring to same view.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but the filter does not do its job now. I obtain the whole collection at both places. What could it be?

Comment: At least you should point out **What's wrong** with the default view, I think the default view is just for convenient, we can always change the Filter and achieve what we want.

Comment: @KingKing - Updated with the reason.

Comment: @Sturm - When you create the view, were all objects are there in source collection or you added them later after initialization? Try calling `ViewMacros.Refresh()` in case of later.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that the problem comes from ViewMacros.Refresh() and the reason is a NullReferenceException: SourceCollection is null. I don't know why, I think I initialized all properly.

Comment: It might be possible when you instantiate `ViewMacros`, `CreatedMacros` was null at that time. Make sure your source collection is initialized first before initializing a view on top of it.

Comment: It's odd, because ViewMacros can't be null, it's beeing bound to the ItemsControl, and I can see the displayed items. But when I try to refresh it crashes. Thanks for your help, I'll try to investigate the problem...

Comment: Are you able to find out the reason for null reference?